# Secured HTTP Proxy over different ESB Products

Tags: rest, authentication, wso2, mule, wso2-esb

Im currently evaluating different ESB Products (in fact im focuding on mule right now). The Use Case is to proxy a simple HTTP Service, an OpenGIS Web Mapping Service WMS.

Here is an example of an freely published WMS Service:

- it responds with XML Metadata about the Service for a "GetCapablities" Request (http://www.wms.nrw.de/wms/uebersicht_nrw2?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS)
- it responds with Image data containing a map for a "GetMap" Request (http://www.wms.nrw.de/wms/uebersicht_nrw2?REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=Uebersicht&SRS=EPSG:31466&FORMAT=image/png&BBOX=2538900,5656400,2619500,5777000&WIDTH=200&HEIGHT=200&STYLES=&)

Both returns its data as a byte array, which could possibly be the problem i am dealing with.

After I can proxy it through Mule ESB, I want to add security features as follows:

- HTTP Basic and Digest Authentication
- Authentication via TLS Client certificates
- Implementing a XACML Policy Enforcement Point
- provide some usage statistics over auditing services and implement some QoS and Throttling on it.

But basically the proxy itself isn't working as i want it to. Here is what I got so far. First I tried to proxy it with a flow to add a security provider on the inbound-adress. but the request doesn't seem to get through to the outbound-adress, and the response is empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security" xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="...cut..."
<mule-ss:security-manager>  
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager"/> 
</mule-ss:security-manager>
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <ss:authentication-provider> 
            <ss:user-service id="userService"> 
                <ss:user name="ross" password="ross" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>  
                <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON"/> 
            </ss:user-service> 
        </ss:authentication-provider> 
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>
<flow name="wfsFlow1" doc:name="wfsFlow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="wms" responseTimeout="10000000" doc:name="Geoserver OWS">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://www.wms.nrw.de/wms#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" encoding="UTF-8" disableTransportTransformer="true" responseTimeout="1000000" doc:name="Geoserver OWS"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

I think the problem is the response from the WMS Service as byte array. I tried different repsonse transformers to transform from byte array to string or html response, but it didn't work.

I also tried the bridge pattern, but it wasn't providing the parameters with the GET Operation as i expected but by POST, which is not accepted by the underlying WMS Service.

I think my Use Case is pretty simple, but im trying to implement it since four weeks now. I did every sample Tutorial these vendors provided, but i wasn't able to set up a simple HTTP Parameter service with any kind of authentication.

Does anybody have any experiences with these products or would beso nice to answer me some specific questions on how to set up a HTTP Proxy with authentication on any of these products.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule relies on Spring Security when it comes to authenticate and authorize people.

[Configuring Security](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Security) is the documentation entry point for dealing with security in Mule. You'll find there information on configuring Spring Security, securing components (like your HTTP bridge) and LDAP authentication.

By default Mule serializes its session into an HTTP header when performing outbound requests. This not only can be a security issue if the remote site is not trusted, but it can also lead to Bad Request issues because the serialized session yields a too large HTTP header.

Knowing that when a security context is present, the Mule Session becomes pretty big, this can cause problem. And indeed, using your config, I was receiving bad request errors from my remote test site! So I added the following to ensure Mule doesn't send its requests over HTTP:

```
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>
```

Also I removed `disableTransportTransformer="true"` from your config because this can cause issues too.

Comment: Thanks, was able to add a mule realm to my Project and authenticate via it. Unfortunately the HTTP Bridge doesnot response any more after authenticating (don't know why this happens when a authentication header is added to the message). Is there an example anywhere explicitely for proxiing HTTP Messages consisting of URL Parameters?

Comment: Show your config and a test request so we can investigate further please.

Comment: Hi Dave! I updated my original question. Configuring Spring Security isn't a problemanymore and works like a charm, but I'm experiencing problems in working with this special flavor of WMS Service I try to proxy. I would be very thankful, if you can give me advice on using either a Flow or kind of a pettern to achieve my requirements.

Comment: Phew, I had to trace HTTP requests to find out what the problem was with your config. It was a very nasty one! Reviewed my configuration accordingly.

Comment: Yay! It works perfectly! I also thought, that the MULE Session Header could possibly cause problems, but I didn't know how to remove it. Thank you so much! Now Mule really gets interesting to me, because I'm able now to use it as a security Middleware Layer for these unsecured OpenGIS WMS and WFS Service Standards. That's really cool! (Btw. Sorry, I dont have enough reputation to score this answer up, but I will do it as soon as possible)

Comment: I'm glad it works! Interesting stuff around GIS you're doing here. Hay maybe one day you'd like to be interviewed on MuleSoft's blog (like http://goo.gl/ETlQj) about your project? Let me know. Finally, you may  have enough reputation to accept my answer?

Comment: Yes, for sure. But first give me some months (or perhaps years?) to train all the possibilties of this (and other ESB) products. This was just the beginning and I am still feeling like a newbie. Now I need some more sophisticated security features, monitoring, throttling, load blancing, dynamic auth. policies based on usage, content based routing either on the Request (based on the URL Parameter) and on the response (based on XML content). Then I'll focus on the performance impact of this. But all that will be part of some other questions, I think ;)

Answer (score 2):

David, your requirement is lengthy. Let me clarify some points on the WSO2 ESB so you can get started.

1. WSO2 ESB supports a variety of transports and content types not just SOAP. You may be most interested in the REST and probably JSON support. Links at [here](http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/04/wso2-esb-tips-tricks-09-introduction-to.html) and [here](http://wso2.org/library/webinars/2011/11/rest-amp-api-management-wso2-esb) may help.
2. All WSO2 servers can be plugged into an external Directory service. [Click here for instructions](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Using+External+User+Stores+%28LDAP+AD%29).
3. All your requirements can be covered. You can go through the comprehensive samples at [this location](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Running+ESB+Samples) to get a feel for what the ESB can do. Let me also point you to the articles at [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Exposing+a+Non-secured+Service+with+Security+Using+ESB), [here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/06/securing-web-service-integration), [here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform), [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Statistics) and [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Throttling) that would help you with your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for all these instructions. At the time I'm focussing on mule, but i will give it a try with wso2 also later on.

Comment: Hello Again Mathew! As I understand this, WSO2 uses SOAP and WS-* Standards internally for Mediation (over the Apache Synapse Mediator). It's also capable of defining RESTful (also URLencoded Request?) Inbound Endpoints and then converts the message to SOAP for internal processing.  But is it also capable of proxiing a simple web page which delivers Plain XML or Image Data as the WMS service above does? I just want the ESB to be completely transparent für the client, and then add HTTP Authentication to the Endpoint.

Comment: The ESB is not just limited to SOAP or WS-* standards. It can support different protocols like JMS, SMTP even and different content types, my it be SOAP, XML, JSON or anything else. It's based on a modular architecture. I won't go too deep into that but look up transport receivers/senders and message builders/formatters if you're interested in details. It's not just URL encoded requests, a complete RESTful interface can be developed. Hope you were able to go through some of the articles I pointed out.